# How can I add lots of authors (8 or so) without overfilling the area?

Tags: pdftex, author-number

I am writing a document for a group project and I obviously want to include everyone who was worked on this documentation but I'm not sure how I should properly add so many authors to one LaTeX document. Currently I am using the following code, but it returns the error `Overfull \hbox` when I then use `\maketitle`.

```
\title{Group Project - Project Specification}
\author{Anna Laura, John Batty, John Friend, Jack Cridland, Kamil Lewinsky, Leon Hassan, Punit Shah and Rowan Alexander}

\maketitle
```

How can I stop the box from overfilling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\and` to separate authors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Group Project - Project Specification}
\author{Anna Laura \and John Batty \and John Friend \and Jack Cridland \and Kamil Lewinsky \and Leon Hassan \and Punit Shah \and Rowan Alexander}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you want more, look in to `authblk` package.